# Update using self join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure as follows in oracle:

```
create table uet_tmp_course
(
    "COURSE_ID" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CODE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREDIT_HRS" NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LEVEL_ID" NUMBER(2,0),
  "STATUS" NUMBER(2,0),
  "COURSE_TYPE_ID" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
  "EQUIVALENCE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  "LAB_CODE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),

     CONSTRAINT "PK_COURSE1" PRIMARY KEY ("COURSE_ID"),

     CONSTRAINT "UK_COURSE_CODE1" UNIQUE ("CODE")
);
```

I want to update the column lab_code's value (i.e. the 8th column) with the course_id instead of code. For example, in the first row instead of 'SE-101L', I want to have '102' i.e. the course_id of 'SE-101L'. I have tried joins, but they result in errors like parenthesis missing or single row query returns more than one row. I would be glad if someone can help. 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the thing you have tried so we can help you get to the solution

Comment: update (  
SELECT  b.course_id as "new_code",a.course_id as "old"
    FROM uet_tmp_course a  LEFT JOIN uet_tmp_course b  
    ON a.lab_code = b.code order by b.course_id) t
    set t.old= t.new_code;

this results in 't.new_code' invalid identifier error

Comment: You are aware that the data isn’t matching today, row 1 has the lab_code of row 2? But perhaps that’s why you want to change it.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, the lab_code is a course_id of a course's offered lab. So yes, I want to update it to course_id of respective lab.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for sharing this, I would keep that in mind on my next question. I am a new user here.

Comment: @Rida, It would be helpful if you edited your question and replaced the screenshot with formatted code. You can do that by enclosing the SQL statement in the backtick `\`` character.

Comment: @Nathan should I update the data image as well?

Comment: Ideally, yes you would not have images of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will update the referenced `course_id` of corresponding `lab_code`.

```
UPDATE a
FROM uet_tmp_course a
INNER JOIN uet_tmp_course b
ON a.LAB_CODE = b.CODE
SET a.LAB_CODE = b.course_id;
```

For Oracle

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT t1.LAB_CODE as OLD, t2.course_id as NEW
 FROM uet_tmp_course t1
 INNER JOIN uet_tmp_course t2
 ON t1.LAB_CODE = t2.CODE
) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

And there is something else you could do to prevent updating rows every time (remeber to manage this in your app too):

```
alter table uet_tmp_course
add constraint FK_uet_tmp_course_lab
foreign key (lab_code) references uet_tmp_course(course_id)
```

Comment: Isn't this mssql syntax. I don't think oracle supports join update.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for observation. I added sintax for Oracle

Comment: Thank you for the reply. the query results in "set keyword missing" error. This table is temporary table for refining data that is why I haven't applied any constraints. I will keep this constraint in mind when constructing the final table. thank you once again :)

Comment: Thank you for the oracle version of the query. It works. Thank you so much

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, this is the query that I initially started with before posting a question here.
update ( SELECT b.course_id as "new_code",a.course_id as "old" FROM uet_tmp_course a LEFT JOIN uet_tmp_course b ON a.lab_code = b.code order by b.course_id) t set t.old= t.new_code;

But this kept giving me error that the term after the last equal is never recognized. why is that? could you please explain. I'm asking this cause your query seems very similar to mine and works absolutely fine.

Comment: Because you are trying to update a Primary key column. Check your sub select, you are selecting course_id.

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto thank you so much for explaining. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`update uet_tmp_course set lab_code = (select course_id from uet_tmp_course where code = lab_code)` should do what you want

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This results in null. whole column of lab_code is now updated to 'null'

Comment: big sry. forgott about the alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
UPDATE uet_tmp_course
SET lab_code = (select course_id
                from uet_tmp_course
                where code=lab_code);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. this query doesn't give me the desired results, instead it updates the lab_code to the respective row's course id.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this syntax (*tab* distincts that column *tab.lab_code* is from outer table):

```
update uet_tmp_course tab
   set tab.lab_code = (select course_id
                         from uet_tmp_course
                        where code = tab.lab_code)
```

Comment: No problem. :)
I'm glad I could've helped ;)

Comment: @Rida I'm glad that we as stack overflow users succeeded to help you. That being said, it's a bit demoralizing seeing ones' answer recognized as a correct one, also being written correctly before the answer latter tagged as correct - and then overlooked.